# How do I use python to iterate JSON output with repeating sets of the same keys?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to use python to create hundreds of repeating sets of JSON output that looks like this:

```
    {
      "children": [],
      "dependencies": [],
      "id": "123456",
      "name": "Epic 1",
      "legend": "",
      "optimistic": "13",
      "pessimistic": "15",
      "expected": "14",
      "min": 13,
      "max": 15,
      "distribution": 0,
      "estimate": 0,
      "discrete": false,
      "isProject": false,
      "state": 1
    },
    {
      "children": [],
      "dependencies": [],
      "id": "234567",
      "name": "Epic 2",
      "legend": "",
      "optimistic": "17",
      "pessimistic": "19",
      "expected": "18",
      "min": 17,
      "max": 19,
      "distribution": 0,
      "estimate": 0,
      "discrete": false,
      "isProject": false,
      "state": 1
    }
...
...
... and so on ...
```

But when I use code like this, each new set overwrites the last, so I only end up with one set in the end.

```
epicdict = {}
for epic in query:
  epicdict.update({"id": epic.id, "name": epic.key, "legend": "", "optimistic": opt, "pessimistic": pes, "expected": exp, "min": 0, "max": 0, "distribution": 0, "estimate": 0, "discrete": True, "isProject": True, "state": 1})
print(epicdict)

with open(jsonfile, 'w') as output:
    json.dump(epicdict, output)
```

How do I build out the JSON output without overwriting anything?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're creating a dict, not a set, when you do `epicdict = {}`, so what you're really doing in that code is updating the same dict with keys/values (overriding them).
What you want is to use `set()` and `.add()`.
It would look like this:

```
epicdict = set()
for epic in query:
  epicdict.add({"id": epic.id, "name": epic.key, "legend": "", "optimistic": opt, "pessimistic": pes, "expected": exp, "min": 0, "max": 0, "distribution": 0, "estimate": 0, "discrete": True, "isProject": True, "state": 1})
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Matheus! However, I'm getting an error with that. Any ideas?

epicdict.add({"id": epic.id, "name": epic.key, "legend": "", "optimistic": 0, "pessimistic": 0, "expected": 0, "min": 0, "max": 0, "distribution": 0, "estimate": 0, "discrete": True, "isProject": True, "state": 1})

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Can you use key/value pairs in a set?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using "append". I am able to keep appending to the set underneath "root".

```
epicset = {"root": []}
epicset["root"].append({"children": ["456def"], "dependencies": [], "id": "123abc", "name": "root", "legend": "", "optimistic": 0, "pessimistic": 0, "expected": 0, "min": 0, "max": 0, "distribution": 0, "estimate": 0, "discrete": True, "isProject": True, "state": 1})
```